# pgRouting only partially segments network?

Tags: pgrouting

I have a road network traced from an old map with 360 MultiLineString features in table aroads. Many meet at endpoints or intermediate vertices, but some intersect.

When I run `SELECT pgr_nodeNetwork('aroads', 0.0001)` many are segmented properly (now 899 features in aroads_noded), but many are skipped. pgr_analyzegraph() detects 79 intersections before and 27 after.

[image]

Can't split this intersection (and others) for the life of me, any ideas?

---

Before (aroads) --

```
NOTICE:              ANALYSIS RESULTS FOR SELECTED EDGES:
NOTICE:                    Isolated segments: 33
NOTICE:                            Dead ends: 193
NOTICE:  Potential gaps found near dead ends: 116
NOTICE:               Intersections detected: 79
NOTICE:                      Ring geometries: 0
```

After (aroads_noded) --

```
NOTICE:              ANALYSIS RESULTS FOR SELECTED EDGES:
NOTICE:                    Isolated segments: 6
NOTICE:                            Dead ends: 78
NOTICE:  Potential gaps found near dead ends: 1
NOTICE:               Intersections detected: 27
NOTICE:                      Ring geometries: 0
```

Comment: There is an reported bug in `pgr_nodeNetwork` [#280](https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/issues/280), still open. I've applied the PR [#282](https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/pull/282) manually in my system, but it's not working properly anyway.